# Is it possible to return a value eg Image Url, from a cloud storage trigger function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

```
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(fileBucket);

const metadata = {
  contentType: contentType,
};

const downloadResponse = await bucket.file(filePath).download();

const imageBuffer = downloadResponse\[0\];

functions.logger.log("Image downloaded!");

// Generate a thumbnail using sharp.

const thumbnailBuffer = await sharp(imageBuffer).resize({
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  withoutEnlargement: true,
}).toBuffer();

functions.logger.log("Thumbnail created");

// Upload the thumbnail with a 'thumb\_' prefix.
const thumbFileName = thumb\ _$ {
  fileName
};

const thumbFilePath = path.join(path.dirname(filePath), thumbFileName);

await bucket.file(thumbFilePath).save(thumbnailBuffer, {
  metadata: metadata,
});

return functions.logger.log("Thumbnail uploaded!");
});
```

I tried the following solution

```
// Download file from bucket.
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(fileBucket);
const metadata = {
  contentType: contentType,
};
const downloadResponse = await bucket.file(filePath).download();
const imageBuffer = downloadResponse\[0\];
functions.logger.log("Image downloaded!");

// Generate a thumbnail using sharp.
const thumbnailBuffer = await sharp(imageBuffer).resize({
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  withoutEnlargement: true,
}).toBuffer();
functions.logger.log("Thumbnail created");

// Upload the thumbnail with a 'thumb\_' prefix.
const thumbFileName = thumb\ _$ {
  fileName
};
const thumbFilePath = path.join(path.dirname(filePath), thumbFileName);
await bucket.file(thumbFilePath).save(thumbnailBuffer, {
  metadata: metadata,
});
return // potential bucket file image url;
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen with the value that you return from the Cloud Function?

Comment: Hello @FrankvanPuffelen I have a wierd situation where whenever I resize an image using the sharp library, If I try to display the final resized image to my client app, the function that is supposed to fetch the resized image would throw an exception

Comment: A storage doesnt exist exception.. but if the resizing cloud function executes quickly and saves the resized image much quicker back to the storage bucket, then my client app would successfully fetch the new resized image.

Comment: In a wierd case, I am forced to recursively try to query for the new resized image, which leads to hundreds of unecessary calls to the cloud storage bucket, since I have no easy way of finding out if the resizing cloud function has successfully resized and resaved the new resized image back into the storage bucket.

Comment: If you get an error, add the exact message and stack trace of that error to your question - by clicking the edit link under it.

Comment: Noted, but the reason for the error is because my client function that tries to fetch the newly resized image, executes before the resizing cloud function finishes executing

Comment: Hence i am asking for a strategy ub which I can ensure the resizing cloud function has finished executing first and has saved the newly resized image back to the bucket, before my client function would attempt to fetch it?

Comment: So the core of my question is @FrankvanPuffelen after successfully executing an onFinalized function "exports.firstGenGenerateThumbnail = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
  // ...
});" can I simply return a String eg" return "resizing success" as opposed to returning "functions.logger.log("Thumbnail created")

Comment: All that information should be present inside your question, not in comments under it. Please click the `edit` link under your question, and ensure all the information that someone would need to answer is in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your `onFinalize` function only triggers when the image has completely uploaded. There is no direct way for the client to wait for whatever you do in that Cloud Function to complete.

The common way to communicate information back from Cloud Functions to the client is through either Firestore or Realtime Database.